# How to specify fields shown in Slack when publishing a Slack Message from Flow?

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

We are using the `Slack: Post Message` Apex Action in Flow to publish a Slack Message when an field value is changed on Opportunity. The default fields when the message is posted in Slack are:

- Close Date
- Opportunity Stage
- Next Step

However, we would like to change these fields, but it is not clear where this can be done in the "Slack Setup" in Salesforce.

Per Mohith's recommendation below, I created an Slack Record Layout to include additional fields, selected the profiles (including mine) who would see it, but when new messages post to Slack, it doesn't show the new fields.

Also, I configured a URL Unfurling Layout and added the fields I wanted to see, and assigned it to my profile (System Admin), and posted a link to the Opportunity in Slack, and it still does not include the additional fields.

Mohith asked if I'm using "Sales cloud Slack app that comes natively". We we using the native integration only. It appears the admin setup all the native features, so I'm not sure which one I'm "using". Since all the native features are enabled, I guess it could be accurate to say I'm using all of them. But I'm only using the `Slack: Post Message` Flow Apex Action at this time, so I'm not sure if that's part of the "Sales cloud Slack app that comes natively".

The only place I can find where to configure fields to show is for custom objects only under the "Slack Setup" app. But there appears to be no obvious way to configure fields for standard objects, like Opportunity.

1. Is it possible to change the default fields shown using the built in Slack integration feature, and if so, how?
2. If not, is there another method of posting a Slack message from Flow that includes the specific fields I choose for Opportunity?

Per Mohith's request, here's a screenshot of the App in Slack:

[image]

[image]

Finally, I did find [this conversation](https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D53a00008WLRK7CAP/how-can-i-modify-the-fields-shown-when-you-include-a-record-link-from-salesforce-in-an-automated-slack-message-from-salesforce?language=en_US), which if I'm reading this correctly, suggests that it is not possible to control the fields shown in Slack that are posted from Salesforce... hopefully I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshots, I suggest to simply use native Salesforce Integration to Slack and Apps.

The app you have in there is pretty old. There is a new app that has more native integrations and capabilities. It is called **Salesforce for Slack App**

[image]

It will require some set up to get it working as outlined in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396436/how-to-post-message-to-slack-using-system-user/396438#396438).

You can then try creating an URL Unfurl Slack Layout as mentioned in the docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps_digital_hq_unfurl_record_layout.htm&type=5)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith. To confirm, these "Slack Record Layouts" control the fields that are down in **Slack** not Salesforce, correct? So if a new Slack Message is posted via a Salesforce Flow, the fields specified here will be shown, correct?

Comment: I believe so. Let me know if this does not work. Thank you

Comment: Mohith, that did not work. I created an Slack Record Layout to include additional fields, selected the profiles (including mine) who would see it, but when new messages post to Slack, it doesn't show the new fields.

Comment: That's odd! Let me research further and get back to you. What happens if you directly post a link to Salesforce record over there and configure the link url unfurl?

Comment: Ok it should work. Here are instructions. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps_sales_prepare_your_org_for_sales_cloud_for_slack.htm&type=5 Try to assign it to a record type and see if it works.

Comment: Also to confirm I want to make sure you are using Sales cloud Slack app that comes natively?

Comment: Mohith, I updated my question with answers to your questions. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "Try to assign it to a record type and see if it works". Your help article doesn't talk about that, so what do you mean?

Comment: @SwisherSweet Would you mind screenshot of the Slack app that you have installed in the Slack instance?

Comment: @SwisherSweet What you are using is pretty old I must say. Try using the newer app as I have answered and it will give you more capablities.